# Redis / Memcached daily clear of cache

Tags: cache, redis, memcached

I have a problem with my Magento 1.9.2.3 stores in that every morning I wake up and the Admin says "One or more of the cache types are invalidated..." and I need to clear the cache. Previously I have set up a cron job to delete the var/cache folder at 6am every morning which worked fine. However, I would like to use Redis or Memcached now but am not sure how I could clear the cache with these automatically like cron. And is the solution the same for both Redis and Memcached?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100922/one-or-more-of-the-cache-types-are-invalidated-blocks-html-output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851909/how-do-i-delete-everything-in-redis

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/259114/how-to-restart-clear-memcache-without-restarting-the-whole-web-server